# Why VSCode shows ReferenceError: router is not defined?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

My users router file

```
const express = require('express');
const { protect, authorize } = require('../middleware/auth');

const {
  createUser,
  getallUsers,
} = require('../controllers/users');

const User = require('../models/User');

const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.route('/')
  . get(authorize('admin').getallUsers)
  . post(createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Method getallUsers

```
exports.getallUsers = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const all = await User.find();

  if (!User) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse('Something got wrong with users collection', 500),
    );
  }

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: all });
});
```

Worked fine before I added getallUSers. Now terminal shows

```
/home/milenko/blog_mongo/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

VSCode shows

```
router.route('/')
^

ReferenceError: router is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/milenko/blog_mongo/backend/routes/tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1:1)
```

How it comes? I set a breakpoint at line 13 router.route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of get method separate authorize('admin') and getallUsers by comma instead of putting dot.